# Is it acceptable to bump a question by editing it?

Tags: support, edits

Some of my old questions have rather low views and have been buried by newer posts. I think that these questions are not worth putting a bounty on them. The edit feature allows the question to reappear on the top of the questions list.

Is the practice to edit a question just to make it temporarily reappear on the top of the questions list acceptable? Or is it frowned upon by the community?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can edit to bump it, but please edit it with something constructive and useful, don't edit just for the sake of bumping. In other words, edit something worthy of editing, not just for the bump. Think of bumping as a positive side effect of the edit.

As Jon Clements comments, editing for the sake of bumping is high frowned upon as it's unnecessary and abusive. It will have consequences.

Comment: ＋１  a positive side effect.

Comment: Just to note: making edits purely for the bump is frowned on and does get noticed. If it's fairly obviously just trying to get the post back on the front page then it might end up with being contacted by a moderator.